# In C#, can I declare a property so that it can return just one of two types

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, types, properties

I have a property (well, lots of them), that I currently have declared as object, but that I'd like to be able to restrict down to just two types. For example, I want a property that will either take a bool, or an instance of a class that contains an expression that will evaluate to a bool within the context that it is used (Expression class includes a string expression which it can parse at runtime and evaluate to a boolean, or error). Equally, I might do something similar with integer, double, DateTime etc.

How could I make a property that would only accept only a value or an instance of an Expression class that will produce that value?

I know that I may be asking something that C# won't natively do, but what would be the closest approximation?

---

Edit: For additional context, these are propeties of object that are being edited using a PropertyGrid in winforms, so that the user can dropdown to select one of {true/false/Expression}, where Expression opens a dialog for editing an Expression, or the user can type it into the PropertyGrid directly. For this reason, it would destroy the ergonomics to have two properties, as in the user's mind it will just be one.

Comment: You could declare the property of the simple type and then add a method or write-only property that takes the other type and sets the first property based on it.

Comment: Why don't you have *two* properties: one is for the class and another is for `bool` where in `get` you can check class property is not `null`?

Comment: If you control the other type you want to use, you could also implement an implicit conversion to the first type. That would, for instance, allow you to assign your type anywhere a `bool` was expect, if it contained a conversion to type `bool`.

Comment: The question is confusing, starting with that you have a property that takes two types. Sounds like you need a generic class and that property is a generic expression(Maybe better a generic method).

Comment: A property that takes two types? No, this is just a mess that will bite you back in future. Create two distinct properties, eventually, if they need some kind of common code call a common method.

Comment: For info, I'm using the properties declared like this in a PropertyGrid (winforms), so I don't really want to split it into two properties. The user either enters a value (true/false for the boolean example), or can type in an Expression, or open up an Expression window to enter an Expression that will evaluate to that type at runtime.

Comment: You can ! You can do this bu using tuple:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit: For additional context, these are propeties of object that are being edited using a PropertyGrid in winforms, so that the user can dropdown to select one of {true/false/Expression}, where Expression opens a dialog for editing an Expression, or the user can type it into the PropertyGrid directly. For this reason, it would destroy the ergonomics to have two properties, as in the user's mind it will just be one.

The idiomatic solution in C# would be to create a dedicated class representing the possible choices, e.g.

```
class UserChoice
{
     public bool? BooleanValue { get; }
     public Expression ExpressionValue { get; }

     // The factory methods ensure that exactly one of BooleanValue
     // and ExpressionValue is not null.

     public static FromBoolean(bool value) => new UserChoice(value, null);

     public static FromExpression(Expression expression)
     {
         if (expression is null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(expression));
         }
         return new UserChoice(null, expression);
     }
     
     private UserChoice(bool? booleanValue, Expression expressionValue)
     {
         BooleanValue = booleanValue;
         ExpressionValue = expressionValue;
     }
}
```

This would be the basic structure. Possible improvements are:

- Static `UserChoice.True` and `UserChoice.False` fields returned by `FromBoolean`. You now have reference equality for True/False values.
- An `Evaluate` method that either returns the Boolean or evaluates the expression.
- `IsBoolean` and `IsExpression` convenience properties.

Comment: thanks. This looks like the route I should go down. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MarkRoworth: Regarding *"Equally, I might do something similar with integer, double, DateTime etc."*: In that case, it should be possible to generalize this class to a `class PrimitiveOrExpression<T> where T : struct { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can achieve the behaviour with a help of `implicit operator` (see my code below), but
do you really want "two types" property? Isn't a better design to have *two* properties?

```
// Class that evaluates to bool
public class MyBoolClass {

  // Stab class which evaluates to constant bool
  public class MyBoolClassStub : MyBoolClass {
    internal MyBoolClassStub(bool value) {
      Value = value;
    }

    public bool Value { get; }

    public override bool ToBool() => Value;
  }

  // Stub class which returns true whenever evaluates to bool
  public static MyBoolClassStub EverTrue { get; } = new MyBoolClassStub(true);

  // Stub class which returns flase whenever evaluates to bool
  public static MyBoolClassStub EverFalse { get; } = new MyBoolClassStub(false);

  public virtual bool ToBool() {
    //TODO: here we evaluate to bool; put relevant code
  }

  public static implicit operator bool(MyBoolClass value) =>
    value?.ToBool() ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)); 

  public static implicit operator MyBoolClass(bool value) =>
    value ? EverTrue : EverFalse;
}
```

Having such a class declaration you can declare property as follow:

```
private MyBoolClass m_MyProperty;

public MyBoolClass MyProperty {
  get {
    if (m_MyProperty is null)
      return false; //TODO: default value here

    return m_MyProperty;
  }
  set {
    m_MyProperty = value;
  }
}
```

And use it

```
// We can assign bool (which will be turned into Stub class)
MyProperty = true;

// We can read bool
if (MyProperty)
  Console.WriteLine("true");

// We can assign "class evaluated to bool"
MyProperty = new MyClass();

Console.WriteLine(MyProperty ? "yes" : "no");
```